# Как привести клавиатуру к верхнему регистру?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть editText, который я прослушиваю с помощью textChangedListener.
Код:

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {          
                String [] sym = String.valueOf(s).split("");
                if(sym[sym.length -1].matches("[a-z1-9H]"))//тут надо привести клавиатуру в верхний регистр;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
    });
```

В методе beforeTextChanged я создаю массив и заполняю его символами, введёнными с клавиатуры, затем, если пользователь ввёл цифру или маленькую букву или "H", то клавиатура должна перейти в верхний регистр (причём только для следующей буквы). То есть это как textCapWords, только " пробелом" должны служить цифры, маленькие буквы и "H".
Обрыл весь интернет, но ничего подобного не нашёл.

Резюме: есть editText, который переходит в верхний регистр, если перед этим была введена цифра, маленькая буква, "H".
Прошу вашей помощи, уважаемые знатоки!

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте следующую строку в свой EditText:

```
android:inputType="textCapWords|textCapSentences"
```

Comment: @moonday нужно в комментариях писать

Comment: Вы читали вопрос?

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете программно установить `inputType` при совпадении шаблона и сбросить его в другом случае. Для этого создайте кастомный класс, реализующий `TextWatcher` и передайте в него экземпляр `EditText`:

```
public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

   private EditText et;

   public CustomTextWatcher(EditText et) {
       this.et = et;
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       if (s.subSequence(s.length() - 1, s.length()).toString().matches("[a-z1-9H]")) {
           et.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
       } else {
           et.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
       }
   }
}
```

И установите в качестве слушателя нужному `editText`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(editText));
```